# always show archived tasks in org-agenda

Tags: init-file, org-agenda, archive-mode

Good day!

I have this line of code in my .emacs:

```
(require 'org-agenda)
(setq org-agenda-archives-mode t)
```

Basically I want agenda items to be extracted from archive file.

As soon as I start emacs and invoke agenda, I can see the files from my archive files.

**Problem:**

However, if I close the agenda window and open it again using the same command, I can see agenda entries, but without the ones from the archive. If I restart emacs, I can see the archived task once again, only for the first time and then they dont show up again.

As I understand I need to invoke that command every time I want it to be activated.

But is there a way to activate in a way so it works all the time, I invoke it or not?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use a current version of org-mode, but in the older versions I see instances where code sets the value of `org-agenda-archives-mode` to a `nil` value; e.g., when quitting the org-agenda buffer with `org-agenda--quit`.  Thus, you probably want to let-bind the variable to a non-nil value when calling functions that generate the org-agenda buffer, and/or include a non-nil value in the relevant `org-agenda-custom-commands`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `org-agenda-archives-mode` is not meant to be a customizable option: it is meant to be set from the agenda dispatcher for the duration of that agenda. So Org mode feels free to reset the value at will, as @lawlist mentions in a comment.

Assuming that you have followed the suggestion in the manual to bind the Org agenda dispatcher to `C-c a` in the global keymap, then the way it is meant to be used is with `C-c a a` to bring up the weekly/monthly/whatever agenda and then `v A` to enable `org-agenda-archives-mode`.

I don't think there is an option to set it once and forget it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NickD. (v A) works for me just fine, so I will stick with that for now.